# IIS route requests between two sites by cookie

Tags: iis, routes, iis-6, load-balancing, horizontal-scaling

I have the following issue :
How to route requests to different IIS sites by some cookie value ?
Main feature of the solution could be a simplest implementation because this is a temporary solution.

I have `IIS v. 6.2`